# WiX Burn custom bootstrapper: ExecuteProgress event is fired continuously after user cancelled the installation

Tags: wix, burn

In my `ExecuteProgress` callback, if a user cancelled the installation it waits for the user to confirm the calcellation(using `AutoResetEvent`) through message box, and after the confirmation it sets `e.Result` to `Result.Cancel` requiring Burn engine cancel the installation.

After that `ExecutePackageComplete` callback is called and this is right. But, after that `ExecutePackageBegin` callback is called again for the same MSI package that I request the Burn engine stop install. And then `ExecuteProgress` callback is called again for the same MSI and waits for the user confirmation forever. (This time there is no message box for user confirmation.) How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of the Burn log found in the user's temp directory for questions like this.  I bet Burn is just doing rollback, which is something your BA needs to be aware of.

Comment: @SeanHall Thanks. The log file says Burn is doing rollback. I fixed my problem by distinguishing between the two states: one state that user cancelled but have not confirmed it yet(waitng for user confirmation) and the other state that user confirmed the cancellation. I changed `ExecuteProgress` callback so that it waits for user confirmation only in the former state.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return from the callback if you're prompting for confirmation.  Your BA needs to be aware of rollback - it probably should do things differently while rolling back.